# source code of Eclipse JDT Core v3.4

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

I need the source code of "Eclipse JDT Core" v3.4 . I tried this link:
http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/

but it was confusing for me, there are many things which I couldn't distinguish.

I also need the source code of "lucene" v 2.4.0 . I tried this link:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/

but there were many things called 2.4.0. which one is the source code?

Thanks...

Comment: "there were many things called 2.4.0" - well yes, in that there are zip files and tgz files, as well as signature files. Either zip or tgz file that includes "-src" should be fine. As for the Eclipse part, your question isn't clear...

Comment: Thank you. Both "lucene-2.4.0-src.tar.gz" and "lucene-2.4.0-src.zip" don't include all packages. for example: package "org.tartarus.snowball.ext" is not in either one, also benchmark packages are not.

Comment: No, because that's not part of Lucene itself - it may come *bundled* with Lucene (I haven't checked) but that's not the same thing. A cursory search found http://snowball.tartarus.org/.

Comment: thank you. Would you please help me with "Eclipse JDT Core" v3.4 . I just need its source code (with all of its classes and packages). thanks

Comment: Well you haven't explained what problem you're facing at the moment. Give more details.

Comment: I don't know which link in this page: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/  has the full source code of "Eclipse JDT Core" v3.4 .

Comment: Well did you try http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/sourceBuilds.php ? (Just looking for the word "source" in the previous page found that very easily...)

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that "Eclipse SDK" source build is the same as "Eclipse JDT Core" ? I found something called "Eclipse JDT Core batch compiler" but I think it is not what I am looking for. Is not it?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the Eclipse SDK source build includes the JDT core, although I could be wrong - have you tried it? Why do you need the source code anyway?

Comment: I need to apply my tool on the source code to measure the package cohesion. I need "Eclipse JDT core" because I already have some bugs data that I am gonna compare with my cohesion measure.

Comment: Can I get it from: http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.jdt.core/developer   the webmaster told me to link to the links in this page but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Well that has a link to https://git.eclipse.org/r/p/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core as the git repository root - so just clone that.

Comment: I couldn't clone it in Eclipse by MercurialEclipse. Is there a way to download v 3.4 directly?

Comment: Well don't use Mercurial, use git - it's a git repository!